# Калькулятор на jquery если отмечен чекбокс умножить на значение

Tags: jquery, checkbox

уважаемые. 
Подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть небольшой калькулятор, который высчитывает цену из двух полей.
После просчета, он сравнивает, какая цена больше и выводит именно ее.
Вопрос такой: У нас есть еще дополнительные 3 чекбокса, и если чекбоксы отмечен, то эта цена должна умножится на определенный коэфицент, и вот тут пока не могу понять как это можно реализовать. Буду признателен за подсказку...

```js
$('#maincalc input#sbt').click(function() {
      var v1 = parseFloat($("#ves").val());
      var v2 = parseFloat($('#obem').val());

      var weight = v1;
      var discounted = weight;

      if (v1 >= 0 && v1 < 100)
        discounted = weight * 13;
      else if (v1 >= 100 && v1 < 300)
        discounted = weight * 12.8;
      else if (v1 >= 300 && v1 < 450)
        discounted = weight * 12.6;
      else if (v1 >= 450 && v1 < 750)
        discounted = weight * 12.4;
      else if (v1 >= 750 && v1 < 1050)
        discounted = weight * 12.2;
      else if (v1 >= 1050 && v1 < 1500)
        discounted = weight * 11.9;
      else if (v1 >= 1500 && v1 < 3000)
        discounted = weight * 11.5;
      else if (v1 >= 3000 && v1 < 5000)
        discounted = weight * 11.3;
      else if (v1 >= 5000 && v1 < 10000)
        discounted = weight * 11;

      var obem = v2;
      var discounted2 = obem;

      if (v2 >= 0 && v2 < 1)
        discounted2 = obem * 2100;
      else if (v2 >= 1 && v2 < 2)
        discounted2 = obem * 2050;
      else if (v2 >= 2 && v2 < 3)
        discounted2 = obem * 2000;
      else if (v2 >= 3 && v2 < 5)
        discounted2 = obem * 1980;
      else if (v2 >= 5 && v2 < 7)
        discounted2 = obem * 1950;
      else if (v2 >= 7 && v2 < 10)
        discounted2 = obem * 1900;
      else if (v2 >= 10 && v2 < 20)
        discounted2 = obem * 1880;
      else if (v2 >= 20 && v2 < 35)
        discounted2 = obem * 1850;
      else if (v2 >= 35 && v2 < 60)
        discounted2 = obem * 1800;

      if (discounted === discounted) {

      } else {

        return 0;
      }
      if (discounted2 === discounted2) {

      } else {

        return 0;
      }

      if (discounted > discounted2)
        $("#calc_price").html("Стоимость:" + discounted + "руб.");
      else
        $("#calc_price").html("Стоимость:" + discounted2 + "руб.");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="content_element" id="maincalc">
  <div style="display: block;">
    <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">

      <div><input id="ves" class="form-control" required style="max-width:350px;" placeholder="Вес (кг)"></div>
      <div></div>

      <div><input id="obem" value="" class="form-control" style="max-width:350px;" placeholder="Объем (м3)" required></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="agreement form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="perevozka1" id="calc_g" class="required">
      <label for="calc_g">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            Перевозка негабаритных грузов: если объем или вес одного места превышает 0,5 куб.м/80кг,либо сумма линейных измерений его габаритов превышает 3 метра (+20% к стоимости)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="agreement form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="perevozka2" id="calc_g2" class="required">
      <label for="calc_g2">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            Перевозка негабаритных грузов: если объем или вес одного места превышает  3 куб.м/500кг (+30% к стоимости)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="agreement form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="perevozka3" id="calc_t" class="required">
      <label for="calc_t">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            Перевозка груза с соблюдением теплового режима(+30% к стоимости)
        </label>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
      <div><b>Экспедирование груза:</b></div>
      <div class="agreement form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="exp1" id="calc_em" class="required">
        <label for="calc_em">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            По Москве
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="agreement form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="exp2" id="calc_ee" class="required">
        <label for="calc_ee">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            По Екатеринбургу
        </label>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:15px;"><input type="button" type="submit" value="Рассчитать стоимость грузоперевозки" id="sbt" class="btn min"></div>
    <div id="calc_price"></div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: вопрос то в чем? что-то не работает или что? зы: ваши портянки с if-ами очень кратко записываются в виде массивов/объектов, но и без них условия там можно упростить наполовину. Дальнейшие сравнения переменных с самой собой тоже несколько странны.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что если еще будут отмечены чекбоксы, которые идут ниже полей, то цена должна еще умножится, в этом и вопрос...

Comment: дак и сложность то в чем? перечислить чекбоксы?  определить, какие чекнуты? связать их со множителями, или что?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let $ves = $('#ves'),
  $obem = $('#obem'),
  $checkbox = $('input[name^="perevozka"]'),
  $sbt = $('#sbt'),
  $calc_price = $('#calc_price'),
  mainRait = 1000; // какой-то базовый коэффициент

$sbt.on('click', function () {
  if (!$ves.val() || !$obem.val()) {
    alert('не заполнены обязательные поля');
    return false;
  }
  
  let s = mainRait * (parseInt($ves.val()) * parseInt($obem.val()));
  
  $.each($checkbox, function (idx, el) {
    if ($(this).attr('data-surcharge') != '0' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
      s = s + s * (parseInt($(this).attr('data-surcharge')) / 100);
    }
  })
  
  $calc_price.html(s);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="content_element" id="maincalc">
  <div style="display: block;">
    <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">

      <div><input id="ves" class="form-control" required style="max-width:350px;" placeholder="Вес (кг)"></div>
      <div></div>

      <div><input id="obem" value="" class="form-control" style="max-width:350px;" placeholder="Объем (м3)" required></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="agreement form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="perevozka1" id="calc_g" class="required" data-surcharge = "20">
      <label for="calc_g">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            Перевозка негабаритных грузов: если объем или вес одного места превышает 0,5 куб.м/80кг,либо сумма линейных измерений его габаритов превышает 3 метра (+20% к стоимости)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="agreement form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="perevozka2" id="calc_g2" class="required" data-surcharge = "30">
      <label for="calc_g2">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            Перевозка негабаритных грузов: если объем или вес одного места превышает  3 куб.м/500кг (+30% к стоимости)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="agreement form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="perevozka3" id="calc_t" class="required" data-surcharge = "30">
      <label for="calc_t">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            Перевозка груза с соблюдением теплового режима(+30% к стоимости)
        </label>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
      <div><b>Экспедирование груза:</b></div>
      <div class="agreement form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="exp1" id="calc_em" class="required">
        <label for="calc_em">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            По Москве
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="agreement form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="exp2" id="calc_ee" class="required">
        <label for="calc_ee">
            <i class="material-icons checked"></i> 
            <i class="material-icons no-checked"></i> 
            По Екатеринбургу
        </label>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:15px;"><input type="button" type="submit" value="Рассчитать стоимость грузоперевозки" id="sbt" class="btn min"></div>
    <div id="calc_price"></div>

  </div>
</form>
```